# If $p$ is a prime then all the non trivial subgroups of $G$ with $\lvert G\rvert=p^2$ are cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, p-groups

> If $p$ is a prime then all the non trivial subgroups of $G$ with $\lvert G\rvert=p^2$ are cyclic.

I tried looking online where does this result come from, but could not find any direct result. I found that all groups with order $p^2$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z_p} \times \mathbb{Z_p}$; is this a consequence of this result?

Comment: Is it $G$ that has order $p^2$ or the nontrivial subgroups of $G$?

Comment: $G$ has order $p^2$.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the classification of groups of order $p^2$. Just use Lagrange theorem to conclude that a nontrivial subgroup (that is, different of the trivial one and $G$) has order $p$.

Now, groups of prime order  $p$ are known to be cyclic (the order of a nontrivial element cannot be $1$, so it is $p$).

Comment: Not sure I follow. By Lagranges theorem if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. Letting $H=\langle x \rangle$, we have that if $x$ is an element of $G$, then $|x|$ divides $|G|$. So if $p^2$ is the order of $G$ then I have that $|x| = 1, p$ or $p^2$?

Comment: I was recalling briefly why  a group of prime order $p$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

If $H\le G$ is nontrivial, then $|H|=p$ (Lagrange). Then $1\ne x\in H\Longrightarrow \langle x\rangle=H$ (Lagrange, again), so $H$ is cyclic.